# Kubernetes service with exactly one pod from a deployment?

Tags: networking, ssh, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I've got a k8s deployment with 3 pods in it and I've set up a NodePort service to forward SSH (port 22) to the 3 pods. Everything works as expected, but each time I SSH in, I get a random pod. I'd like to make it sticky so that I always get the same pod, but I'm unsure if this is possible.

According to [the documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/services/source-ip/#source-ip-for-services-with-type-nodeport), setting `sessionAffinity: ClientIP` probably won't work for NodePorts. I don't think `externalTrafficPolicy: Local` will work because you need to use a LoadBalancer service. I don't think LoadBalancer services are feasible for me because I need to create hundreds of these and each LoadBalancer costs money and uses up quota.

What I'm wondering here is whether it's possible to create a service that doesn't point to all 3 pods in the deployment, but instead exactly 1 pod. That would help for my situation. I could manually attach a special label to 1 pod and set the service selector to that label, but it feels brittle to me in case that pod dies and is replaced.

Comment: _a service that doesn't point to all 3 pods in the deployment, but instead exactly 1 pod_ I hope you can appreciate that kubernetes has the opposite world-view from what you are describing, which is going to continue to make this task harder and harder. Having said that, are you open to writing your [own controller](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/extend-kubernetes/api-extension/custom-resources/#custom-controllers) that watches the pods and moves the label?

Answer (score 1):

One way to get around this would be to create your pods using StatefulSet instead of deployment. Then your pods have a deterministic names, and when restarted, will retain their name. That way you can create a service that points to `myapp-0`, `myapp-1` etc. and be reasonably sure that interruptions, while will break for a while when pod is rescheduled/restarted, will also get back to a working state. You will need to handle automation of such service creation when scaling StatefulSet though and your "affinity" would be based on service port that client is connecting to (can't have multiple services on same port)

That said, this is definitely not a good pattern to follow. You should ensure that your client can connect to any of the pods and that they share required state by means of another service they all use or a shared RWX volume if it's about files.

Comment: Thanks for the thoughtful answer, Radek. If you have any more insight into my problem, I'd love to get your thoughts on an alternative solution that doesn't follow a bad pattern.

In my situation, the 3 pods are running Elixir nodes that want to form a cluster. They communicate with each other on random ports and I want to find out what that port is. If I SSH in and get the port, then try to do something like create an SSH tunnel on that port, I hit a different pod using a different port so it doesn't work.